# Fastest way to solve least square for overdetermined system

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix A of size m*n( m order of ~100K and n ~500) and a vector b. Also, my matrix is ill-conditioned and rank-deficient. Now I want to find out the least-square solution to Ax = b and to this end I have compared some of the methods:

- `scipy.linalg.lstsq` (time/residual) : 14s, 626.982
- `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr` (time/residual) : 4.5s, 626.982 (same accuracy)

Now I have observed that when I don't have the rank-deficient case forming the normal equation and solving it using cholesky factorization is fastest way to solve my problem. So my question is this If I am not interested in the minimum norm solution then is there a way to get a solution(any) to (A^TAx=b) when A^TA is singular. I have tried scipy.linalg.solve but it gives LinAlgError for singular matrices. Also I would like to know if A is such that m>>n, ill-conditonied, possibly not full col-rank then which method should one use in terms of time, residual accuracy(or any other metric). Any thoughts and help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the "correct" way of going about this is to use the SVD, look at your singular value spectrum, and figure out how many singular values you want to keep, i.e., figure out how close you want `A^T x` to be to `b`. Something along these lines:

```
def svd_solve(a, b):
    [U, s, Vt] = la.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
    r = max(np.where(s >= 1e-12)[0])
    temp = np.dot(U[:, :r].T, b) / s[:r]
    return np.dot(Vt[:r, :].T, temp)
```

However, for a matrix of size `(100000, 500)`, this is just going to be way too slow. I would recommend implementing least squares by yourself, and adding a small amount of regularization to avoid the issue of the matrix becoming singular.

```
def naive_solve(a, b, lamda):
    return la.solve(np.dot(a.T, a) + lamda * np.identity(a.shape[1]),
                    np.dot(a.T, b))

def pos_solve(a, b, lamda):
    return la.solve(np.dot(a.T, a) + lamda * np.identity(a.shape[1]),
                    np.dot(a.T, b), assume_a='pos')
```

Here's a timing analysis on my workstation*:

```
>>> %timeit la.lstsq(a, b)
1.84 s ± 39.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit naive_solve(a, b, 1e-25)
140 ms ± 4.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit pos_solve(a, b, 1e-25)
135 ms ± 768 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**I somehow don't seem to have `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr` on my machine, so I couldn't compare against that.*

It doesn't seem to do much here, but I've seen elsewhere that adding the `assume_a='pos'` flag can actually give you a lot of benefit. You can certainly do this here, since `A^T A` is guaranteed to be positive semi-definite, and the `lamda` makes it positive definite. You might have to play with `lamda` a little to bring your error sufficiently low.

And in terms of error:

```
>>> xhat_lstsq = la.lstsq(a, b)[0]
>>> la.norm(np.dot(a, xhat_lstsq) - b)
1.4628232073579952e-13
>>> xhat_naive = naive_solve(a, b, 1e-25)
>>> la.norm(np.dot(a, xhat_naive) - b)
7.474566255470176e-13
>>> xhat_pos = pos_solve(a, b, 1e-25)
>>> la.norm(np.dot(a, xhat_pos) - b)
7.476075564322223e-13
```

PS: I generated an `a` and a `b` of my own like this:

```
s = np.logspace(1, -20, 500)
u = np.random.randn(100000, 500)
u /= la.norm(u, axis=0)[np.newaxis, :]
a = np.dot(u, np.diag(s))
x = np.random.randn(500)
b = np.dot(a, x)
```

My `a` isn't completely singular, but near-singular.

#### Response to comment

I guess what you are trying to do is to find a feasible point under some linear equality constraints. The trouble here is that you don't know which constraints are important. Each of the 100,000 rows of A gives you a new constraint, out of which at most 500, but possibly far fewer (because of underdetermined-ness), actually matter. The SVD gives you a way of figuring out which dimensions are important. I don't know of another way to do this: you might find something in convex optimization or linear programming literature. If you know a priori that the rank of A is `r`, then you can try to find only the first `r` singular values and corresponding vectors, which might save time if `r << n`.

Regarding your other question, the minimum norm solution isn't the "best" or even the "correct" solution. Since your system is underdetermined, you need to throw in some additional constraints or assumptions which will help you find a unique solution. The minimum norm constraint is one such. The minimum norm solution is often considered to be "good", because if `x` is some physical signal which you are trying to design, then an `x` with lower norm often corresponds to a physical signal with *lower energy*, which then translates to cost savings, etc. Alternatively, if `x` is a parameter of some system you are trying to estimate, then choosing the minimum norm solution means you are *assuming* that the system is efficient in some way, and uses only the minimum energy needed to produce the outcome `b`. Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have few questions though, if I am interested in any solution to least square problem, not necessarily minimum norm, then isn't doing svd an overkill. Is there a way(scipy method) to get a solution to normal equations when A^TA is psd without doing regularization(because then your problem is not exactly least square). Also I would like to understand why is the minimum norm solution so preferable in general apart from the reason of simplicity which comes from machine learning literature. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1131274 I've included my response in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks for nicely explaining why minimum norm solution is important sometimes. But regarding my first question aren't we making things complex, I mean if A^TA is psd and we want any solution then isn't doing gaussian elimination on $A^TAx=A^Tb$ and setting free variables to let say 0 work and give us some solution? Am I missing something obvious and if not is there a way to do this in scipy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1131274 `la.solve` does exactly what you say, i.e. Gaussian elimination. If I'm not wrong, to do this you need `A^T A` to be PD, not just PSD. Hence the small addition of `lamda * np.identity(n)`. Also, the idea of "setting free variables to zero" is what gives you the minimum norm solution. Setting them to anything else can only increase the norm.

Comment: la.solve actually does cholesky underneath for pd matrices. Actually, I was hoping to avoid regularization formulation since I only need a solution. Also setting free variables to zero won't necessarily give you minimum norm solution, as the cols of A^TA are dependent there could be a solution using free variable and independent variables which could have even smaller norm. Its not hard to create a counter example to check this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1131274 Oh yes, you're right. I didn't think through my statements carefully. There's no in-built way to do this in numpy as far as I know. I'd suggest looking at cvxpy or implementing your own method, but to really see gains you'll have to write an implementation in C or Cython. Likewise, you'll have to use a fast solver with cvxpy. You'll have to decide if it's all worth it.

Comment: @ Praveen: "SVD gives you a way of figuring out which dimensions are important." i anyway, I suppose, [regularization](https://medium.com/@jaredtjacobsen/an-explanation-of-the-objective-functions-in-regularized-and-ordinary-least-squares-regression-eab68f82fc52) is used for such cases ?