# Fastest way of solving linear least squares

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2233298/340174 it is mentioned that solving a linear equation "M·x = b" (matrix M is square) is slow if done via LU decomposition (but even slower using QR decomposition). Now I noticed that `numpy.linalg.solve` is in fact using LU decomposition. In truth, I want to solve "V·x = b" for a non-squared Vandermonde design matrix V for the least squares. I don't want regularization. I see multiple approaches:

1. Solve "V·x = b" with `numpy.linalg.lstsq`, which uses Fortran "xGELSD" based on SVD. The SVD should be even slower than LU decomposition, but I don't need to calculate "(V^T·V)".
2. Solve "(V^T·V)·x = (V^T·b)" with `numpy.linalg.solve`, which uses LU decomposition.
3. Solve "A·x = b" with `numpy.linalg.solve`, which uses LU decomposition, but calculating "A=xV^T·V" directly according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3155891/340174

Alaternatively I could use the newest `solve` from scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) which can use diagonal pivoting for the symmetric matrix "A" (which is faster than using LU decomposition, I guess), but my scipy is stuck on 1.1.0, so I don't have access to that.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535523/4533188 it seems that `solve` is faster than `lstsq`, including calculating "V^T·V", but when I tried it, `lstsq` was faster. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

**What is the fastest way of solving my linear problem?**

---

#### No real options

- `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit` is uses either Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse or QR-factorization + `np.linalg.inv` + `np.linalg.svd` + `numpy.linalg.solve`, which does not seem too efficient to me.
- `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` uses scipy.linalg.lstsq.
- `scipy.linalg.lstsq` uses also xGELSD.
- I expect calculating the inverse of "(V^T·V)" to be pretty expensive, so I discarded the direct computation of "x = (V^T·V)^-1·(V^T·b)"

Comment: Vandermonde matrix has [analytically expressed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698254/proof-of-vandermonde-matrix-inverse-formula) inverse matrix. I don't dive in deep, and don't know about floating point errors in this case, but this approach should be the fastest.  Also, you can look at `np.linalg.pinv` this is almost "(V^T·V)^-1·V^T"

Comment: @bubble That's a nice resource, but isn't that [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix) for square matrices only? The OP mentions a *non-squared Vandermonde design matrix*

Answer (score 6):

**Give a try to [`scipy.linalg.lstsq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq) using `lapack_driver='gelsy'`!**

Let's review the different routines for solving linear least square and the approches:

- [`numpy.linalg.lstsq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) wraps LAPACK's [`xGELSD()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d6a/dgelsd_8f_source.html), as shown in [umath_linalg.c.src](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src) on line 2841+. This routine reduces the matrix V to bidiagonal form using a devide and conquer strategy and compute the SVD of that bidiagonal matrix.
- scipy's [`scipy.linalg.lstsq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq) wraps LAPACK's `xGELSD()`, [`xGELSY()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/d4b/dgelsy_8f_source.html) and [`xGELSS()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d4e/dgelss_8f_source.html): the argument `lapack_driver` can be modifed to switch from one to another. According to the benchmark of LAPACK, `xGELSS()` is slower than `xGELSD()` and `xGELSY()` is about 5 faster than `xGELSD()`. `xGELSY()` makes use of a QR factorization of V with column pivoting. And the good news is that this switch was [already available in scipy 1.1.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq)!
- LAPACK's [`xGELS()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/dde/dgels_8f_source.html) makes use of the QR decomposition of the matrix V, but it assumes that this matrix has full rank. According to the benchmark of LAPACK, on can expect `dgels()` to be about 5 time faster than `dgelsd()`, but it also more vulnerable to the condition number of the matrix and may become innacurate. See details and further references in [The difference between C++ (LAPACK, sgels) and Python (Numpy, lstsq) results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637108/the-difference-between-c-lapack-sgels-and-python-numpy-lstsq-results) . xGELS() is available in the [cython-lapack interface of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_lapack.html#module-scipy.linalg.cython_lapack).

While very tempting, computing and using `V^T·V` to solve the normal equation is likely not the way to go. Indeed, the precision is endangered by the condition number of that matrix, about [the square of the condition number of the matrix V](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/courses/542g-fall-2008/notes-oct1.pdf). Since [Vandermonde matrices tend to be badly ill-conditioned, except for the matrices of the discrete Fourier transform](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02118), it can become hazardous... **Finally, you may even keep using `xGELSD()` to avoid problems related to conditionning. If you switch to `xGELSY()`, consider [estimating the error](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node82.html).**

Comment: I did some benchmark. See  the new answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to ignore the Vandermonde part of the question (the comment by *bubble* points out that it has an analytic inverse) and answer the more general question about other matrices instead.

I think a few things may be getting conflated here, so I'll distinguish the following:

1. Exact solution of `V x = b` using LU
2. Exact solution of `V x = b` using QR
3. Least-square solution of `V x = b` using QR
4. Least-square solution of `V x = b` using SVD
5. Exact solution of `V^T V x = V^T b` using LU
6. Exact solution of `V^T V x = V^T b` using Cholesky

The first maths.stackexchange answer you linked to is about cases 1 and 2. When it says LU is slow, it means relative to methods for specific types of matrix, e.g. positive-definite, triangular, banded, ...

But I think you're actually asking about 3-6. The last stackoverflow link states that 6 is faster than 4. As you said, 4 should be slower than 3, but 4 is the only one that works for rank-deficient `V`. 6 should be faster than 5 in general.

We should make sure that you did 6 rather than 5. To use 6, you'd need to use `scipy.linalg.solve` with `assume_a="pos"`. Otherwise, you would wind up doing 5.

I haven't found a single function that does 3 in `numpy` or `scipy`. The  Lapack routine is xGELS, which doesn't seem to be exposed in `scipy`. You should be able to do it with `scupy.linalg.qr_multiply` followed by `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular`.

Answer (score 3):

Some benchmark according to @francis 's answer. I turned off `check_finite` to get the best performance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from numpy.linalg import lstsq as np_lstsq
from scipy.linalg import lstsq as sp_lstsq
from scipy.linalg import solve

#custom OLS by LU factorization
def ord_lu(X, y):
    A = X.T @ X
    b = X.T @ y
    beta = solve(A, b, overwrite_a=True, overwrite_b=True,
                 check_finite=False)
    return beta

#load iris dataset for testing
data = load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data.data, columns= data.feature_names)
species = pd.get_dummies(data.target)
y = iris_df.pop('sepal length (cm)').to_numpy()
X = np.hstack([iris_df.to_numpy(), species.to_numpy()])

%timeit -n10000 -r10 result = np_lstsq(X, y)
#33.7 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit -n10000 -r10 result = sp_lstsq(X, y, lapack_driver='gelsd', check_finite=False)
#44.9 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit -n10000 -r10 result = sp_lstsq(X, y, lapack_driver='gelsy', check_finite=False)
#13.5 µs ± 661 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit -n10000 -r10 result = sp_lstsq(X, y, lapack_driver='gelss', check_finite=False)
#43.5 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit -n10000 -r10 result = ord_lu(X, y)
#18 µs ± 360 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Based on the result, `gelsy` is the fastest least-squares algorithm. For unknown reason, in SciPy `gelsd` is even slower than `gelss`, which shouldn't be. But NumPy's `lstsq` (also using `gelsd`) behaves normal and is significantly faster than SciPy's `gelss`.  The custom function using LU factorization is quite fast. But as @francis said, it's not safe.